penalized package
Has anyone used penalized package? I was using it for lasso in Cox regression, with time-varying coefficients.
The problem is when I made a plot with profL1, it seems that the corresponding coefficient value of lambda in the curve was different from what I got in penalized even though I used the same lambda value.
I asked chatGPT and it seems that the coefficient computed with profL1 is different from penalized. However, when it comes to publication, there may be issues that people ask why there is a discrepancy.
Is there anyone who could help? Thanks!
